# Silverlight Out of browser and on demand loading of assembly

Tags: silverlight, browser, assemblies, ondemand

I want my silverlight application to work out of browser and it should support on demand loading of assemblies as well.

If i implement on demand loading of assemblies, what will happen in case of out of browser support, will it work fine? or it will download all the assemblies during the installation itself.

Thanks,
Mrinal Jaiswal

Answer (score 0):

In your case, an exception will be thrown when the code of retrieving the assembly is hit and there is no internet connectivity, whether its running OOB or in a webpage.